# If Else SQL Sscript to Copy Values From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create an If Else SQL Script to copy values from another table where if the column is null, it will copy the value from another table.

Example:

```
update table_name
  set column_a = case
                  when column_a is null then copy value from other table
                  else null
                 end,
  set column_b = case
                  when column_b is null then copy value from other table
                 end,
  set column_c = case
                  when column_c is null then copy value from other table
                 end
where
 table_d_column is null
```

Comment: Why would you want `NULL` values if there is no match?

Comment: I may have written the script wrong, basically if a column in a different table is null, I want to populate the null values of a different table with values from the table of the columns that are null.

Answer (score 4):

Your code would typically be written as:

```
update t
    set column_a = coalesce(t.column_a, ot.column_a),
        column_b = coalesce(t.column_a, ot.column_b),
        column_c = coalesce(t.column_a, ot.column_c)
    from t join
         othertable ot
         on t.? = ot.?
    where column_a is null or column_b is null or column_c is null;
```

Notes:

- An `update` has only one `set clause.
- I assume you want to keep the existing values in each column if they are not `null`.
- The appropriate columns for the `join` should be in the `where` clause.
- If `othertable` has only one row, you can use a `cross join` instead.

Comment: I am trying to update values from another table based off another value being null from another table as well.  If table a_column is null, then copy table_b value to table_a value if table_c value is null.

Comment: @Jeff . . . This question is only about two tables (at least as I read it).  If you have another question, then ask it as a *question*, not a comment.